# Pretty printing not working for stored proc in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write an simple stored procedure to just print out information from three different tables. The problem is that for some reason \G does not work from within a stored proc. I want the output to be readable so this is pretty important

This code works but doesnt display columns in an effective way

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `snapshot`//

 CREATE PROCEDURE snapshot(IN employeeUsername varchar(255))
   BEGIN
   SELECT *  FROM employee where username = employeeUsername;
   END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

This code throws an exception

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `snapshot`//

 CREATE PROCEDURE snapshot(IN employeeUsername varchar(255))
   BEGIN
   SELECT *  FROM employee where username = employeeUsername \G;
   END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `\G` is a command of MySQL Client. [4.5.1.2 mysql Commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\G is an command in MySQL Client and subsequently can not be called from a sql stored proc